# Testing file extension for image linking

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to link an  tag to a profile picture with the user's id as the file name.  However, the extension of the image is dependent on the file extension when it was uploaded by the user.

My question is: how would one go about testing to see if a given image file name exists and cycle through the various file extensions for images.

For example:
Let's say and image is named: 1.jpg, but another is named 2.png.
I would like to implement the following in html:

```
<img src = "' + userId + '.jpg">
```

This will work for the furst user, but not the second.  How would I go about testing the various image file extensions for the src?

Thanks

Comment: assuming your using javascript, you would have to check each version of the image to see which one returns 200 ok. This however is incredibly slow and an awful solution. The best approach is to know the file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"File extensions" (indeed, anything regarding the name of the "file") are meaningless.  *Especially* when it comes to HTTP requests.  This URL could just as easily produce an image file:

```
http://www.example.com/foo.txt
```

Understand that there is no such thing as "files" in HTTP.  There are requests and responses, each of which contain headers and content.  A "file" is just a response with a `content-disposition` header.  An "image" is a response with other headers which specify that it contains image data.

If you don't know the URL of the image, it could literally be *anything*.

> the extension of the image is dependent on the file extension when it was uploaded by the user

In that case you should really be **storing** that information in your database.  Whatever record holds the information for the user's profile would include the URL for the user's profile image.  Use that data to build the `img` element.

Either store the data or enforce a convention.  If you don't do either then you simply don't have that data.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful response.  I will be sure to add that information to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `PHP & MySql` store uploaded images like this

```
user_data/user_id/image.png
```

You can use php `mkdir()` function to create directory with user id

for example

```
mkdir("user_data/".$user_id,0777);
```

So your upload script be something like this

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];
if(!file_exists("user_data/".$user_id."/")){
   mkdir("user_data/".$user_id,0777);
}
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'],user_data/".$user_id."/");
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);//Database connection
$sql = "INSERT INTO uploads(user_id,fileName) VALUES('$user_id','$_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("Unable to update to database");

?>
```

Script for Retrieving Results

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db_name);//Database connection
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM uploads";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $data= mysqli_fetch_array($query);
?>
<img src"user_data/<?php echo "/".$user_id."/". $data['fileName']; ?>
```

There are some varialbes above like `$user_id` which you set & get from session variables